# How can I set a variable from a regular helper method in GSP?

Tags: grails, gsp

I need to output html where the values depend on what kind of object I have (I'm transitioning between DB representations). Right now I have my logic in a block of `g:if` expressions. It's relatively difficult to read and debug.

```
<g:if test="${o.isKindA}">
    <g:set var="x" value="${...}" />
    <g:set var="y" value="${...}" />
    ...
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <g:set var="x" value="${...}" />
    <g:set var="y" value="${...}" />
    ...
</g:else>
```

I am particularly *not* interested in adding these values X and Y as methods of `o`. What I'd like to do is set them using a view helper, which I understand == "tag lib" in grails:

```
// Tag Helper
//
class AmazingTagLib {
    def valueXFor = { attrs -> o.isKindA? 1 : 2 }
    ...
}

// The previous GSP, rewritten
//
...
<g:set var="x" value="${ valueXFor(o) }" />
```

This is failing, however. When I attempt to use `x`, it is bound to an empty StreamCharBuffer, presumably because I didn't attach anything to `out` in the implementation of `valueXFor`. It should have had the integer returned value of my helper.

How can I use such functional helper methods in my view?

Comment: Try adding this just before you define your method in your TagLib: `static returnObjectForTags = ['valueXFor']`

Comment: Omg, @JoshuaMoore, that does it! Submit an answer! You're about to get dozens of points of my co-workers.

Comment: More than happy to help. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that by default Tag Libraries are used to render to `out`. In this case you are looking to return an object/value from your method and you need to tell the `TagLib` that this method is different than the standard behavior. Adding the following will do the trick:

```
class AmazingTagLib {
    static returnObjectForTags = ['valueXFor']
    def valueXFor = { attrs -> o.isKindA? 1 : 2 }
    ...
}
```